# Why do electrons appear more frequently than it's counterpart, positrons?

Tags: particle-physics

Electrons appear in electron clouds of atoms but positrons are found in cosmic rays and radioactive elements. Why do electrons seem more common then positrons?

Edit: Is this an example of asymmetry? I haven't studied it much yet.

Comment: A great mystery of the universe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Baryon asymmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24042/)

Comment: There are other similar questions on the subject of the asymmetry, some of which are linked in the above linked duplicate.